# SQLite primay key setting error - why so?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make Database and table by using DB Handler, and insert datas in MainActivty.

The problem is Data instertig function only worked when I didn't set Primary key.

Here's the log cat.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: keikoTable._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
```

DBhandler.class

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_INFO + "(_id text PRIMARY KEY , year text, " +
            " month text, date text, chek integer, log text)";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public void dbInsert (String year, String month, String date, String log) {
    int doublechk = 0;


     String idCombine = year + month + date + doublechk;

     Cursor cursor = readdb.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_INFO, null);

     while (cursor.moveToNext()){
         if (cursor.getString(0) == idCombine){
             doublechk ++;
             idCombine = year + month + date + doublechk;
         } else {
             break;
         }
     }


    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_INFO  + " VALUES ('" + idCombine + "', '" + year + "', '"+ month  + "', '"
            + date  + "', '" + doublechk + "', '" + log + "')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official guideline [**`SQLiteConstraintException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConstraintException)

> An exception that indicates that an integrity constraint was violated.

You should rectify statement

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_INFO + "( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

And

```
if (cursor.getInt(0) == idCombine){
```

Then ***Uninstall and run again***.